# How can I get the next Primary Key for SQL 2008 in Entity Framework

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using an Entity Framework 4 connection to connect to a SQL 2008 server to do database handling for my application.

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2010 and my question is regarding Primary Key fields that are incremented by the SQL itself, is it possible at all for me to be able to find the ID that will be used next by the database.

The reason why I cannot just find the last item and +1 is because if my table contains items 1,2,3,4 and 5, removing item 5 then adding another will make the next item become item 6, rather than 5 again (As I use the Identity Specification in SQL, but this must be used).

I cannot find any method such as Item.ID.GetNextIdentity() or something like that and have looked through as many similar questions like this but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is your primary key integer?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Ident_Current('Table_Name')

Answer (score 0):

How is your idea about this:

```
var query1=Entities.Select(p=>p.Id).OrderBy(p=>p);
var query2=query1.Select(p=>p+1);
var result=query2.Except(query1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: For example : if i inserted one row in the table and the PK of this row is 1 , and i removed this row and the table now is contain null values , now i want to get the next PK that must be 2